# How to control RC power switch with Arduino-/Adafruit-Board?

Tags: servo, pwm, adafruit, remote-control, switch

I want to control (switch on/off) a solenoid valve via an RC power switch and an Adafruit M0 Feather Bluefruit LE. The RC power switch is [this one](http://shop.pichler.de/Power-Switch-c74-86-7486), and this is the [Adafruit Board Pinout](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-bluefruit-le/pinouts).

My assumption was that I have to wire up the servo wire connector of the power switch with the Adafruit board like I would do with an ESC and control it via PWM (my guide tells me that possible pulse widths are between 870 and 2,220 µs). I am connecting the white cable (I assume it's the impulse wire) of the power-switches' servo-connector with a PWM-capable GPIO pin and the black cable (I assume it's the minus wire) with the GND pin of the Adafruit Board, like I did with an ESC, which is working fine with the servo library of Arduino.

My problem is that the solenoid valve is showing no reaction. Am I thinking the right way or am I completely wrong?

Thank you and many thanks.

Comment: The Code for successfully controlling the escs is like: gist.github.com/vitorleal/9083802

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about RC gear not about Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by myself. If you want to arm an RC power switch, do it like arming an ESC with your sketch. The servo connector wires have to be connected as follows:

- (white) PWM-capable GPIO
- (red) positive wire of your battery
- (black) negative wire of your battery

The simple solution was that the power switches got less/no power.

Comment: "arming" as required by a typical ESC typically means running the throttle PWM up and back down to demonstrate that there's a prepared driver/pilot at the controls.  What you are describing sounds more as if you are simply providing *power* to a switch designed to be powered by the RC receiver rather than to power itself (and potentially also the receiver) from the motor battery.